# Given the value of a determinant what is the quickest way to calculate the value of a determinant which has only one column different?

Tags: determinant, computational-complexity

I have a determinant
$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}\ a_{12}\ a_{13} .... a_{1n}\\
a_{21}\ a_{22}\ a_{23} .... a_{2n}\\
.................\\
.................\\
a_{n1}\ a_{n2}\ a_{n3} .... a_{nn}\\
\end{vmatrix}
=|A| $
now I have replaced let's say the second column with
$
\begin{vmatrix}c_1\\ c_2\\ .\\.\\c_n\\
\end{vmatrix}
$

such that it becomes

$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}\ c_{1}\ a_{13} .... a_{1n}\\
a_{21}\ c_{2}\ a_{23} .... a_{2n}\\
.................\\
.................\\
a_{n1}\ c_{n}\ a_{n3} .... a_{nn}\\
\end{vmatrix}
=?$

I want to know the fastest way to do it.

Comment: if in computing original determinant, you used original second column as pivot, and found sub-determinants of all, then it would be quite easy find new determinant after replacing second column.

Comment: @sku ok lets say for each row and 2nd column as pivot I have n determinantions of dim(n-1) . Now what ?

Comment: “I stumbled upon this problem while solving system of equations using cramer's rule” Why not just use Gaussian elimination to solve the system of equations?

Comment: @littleO I am using Guss elimination only . Sorry I have not made it clear upfront, I have to repeat the same a million times with same ||A|| but different ||C|| . in that case time complexity will become  $O(n^3log(∥A∥)∗n*Million)$ . Updated the question this details.

Comment: But in the “Background” section you said that you were solving a system of equations using Cramer’s rule. Cramer’s rule is a very inefficient way to solve a linear system of equations.

Comment: @littleO sure, now that the problem is clear, feel free to suggest better approaches. dont get hooked on to my method. just to give some background on my attempts I mentioned about my failed efforts.

Comment: @littleO Lets just forget all mathematician's names. uttering names is what is creating such confusion. I am basically finding solution to variable x by  $x=|A_x|/|A|$ . Now I have found out an $O(n^3log(∥A∥)$ complexity way to calculate |A|. so solve one system I need to do that n times and to solve a million systems I need to do that $n*million$ times. Surely there are faster ways as I can see lots of repeated computation just for one systems case, let alone a million.

Comment: I know that my comments are not directly answering your question, but I just want to make sure you're aware of something potentially very useful. If your goal is to solve $Ax = c$ for a million different values of $c$ (but always the same $A$), then what you should probably do is precompute an LU factorization of $A$ (which is a one-time cost) and then use the LU factorization to inexpensively solve $Ax = c$ for each vector $c$. In practice we almost never want to use Cramer's rule when solving linear systems of equations.

Comment: @littleO Ahh Now it did. Let me read up on LU factorization. Meanwhile if you want you can answer it here(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437361/whats-the-fastest-way-to-solve-a-system-of-equations-a-million-times-such-that). I have created a separate question, let this determinant thing remain separate here for someone to optimise.